# I edited the focus of a [too broad] Q, answered it, and OP's edit made it off-topic

Tags: discussion, support

I found a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853590).

The author is a new user and their "question" initially had three parts:

- Their entire life story (or so it seemed)
- A question: Can you suggest any libraries/plugins?
- Another question: How to make a splash screen? (They didn't know what it was called.)

I answered the one part of the question that would be acceptable here (how to make a splash screen.)

I then edited it down to focus on that question.

---

The next day, I see my answer was down voted, and I wondered why. When I arrived at the question, I see the likely reason: the author edited their question to the other question, which is certainly off topic.

What should I do? Can we at least change the close reason to "asking for off-site resources"?

> Note: Since I initially wrote this:
>
> - I added a notice to my answer that I was answering a prior version of the question.
> - I got another down vote.
> - I deleted my answer. I hope to get the Peer Pressure badge finally.
> - Another user rolled back the question to my revision.

Comment: You shouldn't polish turds.  I blame the mythbusters for this.

Comment: You cherry picked from that question the thing that was doable, the splashscreen. The OP is understandably not interest in that detail as it diverts the question too much from their goal. I would have left a comment explaining why you edited the question as you did. The response could have been either *Thanks* or *You screwed up my question*. Implicitly you get that feedback now by the new edit.

Comment: @rene should I delete my answer?

Comment: @Laurel it depends. If you can convince the OP that the edit makes the question reasonable, your answer can stay. If the OP rather gets question banned by having the broad question on their profile, then yes, delete the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is why you don't try to answer bad questions, and also why you shouldn't radically edit the content of someone's question to change what it's asking.  Editing a question to ask something different than what an answer answers isn't a problem when that answerer was the one who changed the question to ask something different from what it was originally asking.  On top of that, the question is an *extremely* poor question even *after* your edits.  It's a resource request before and after your edits, but it's pretty clearly too broad even when it was asking what you edited it to ask, leaving your answer a very incomplete answer to that question.

You should have voted to close the question, and optionally commented explaining what you think the OP might be able to do to improve the question (although personally I doubt the question will ever be salvaged, I'd look elsewhere to spend your time).

Comment: I didn't feel that I was really "changing what it's asking". It DID ask about splash screens, so I focused it on that. In any case, I doubt it's worth my time to go back and VTC once I have enough rep.

Comment: @Laurel Changing it to not ask things it was asking is changing what the question is asking.